# Select Content Builder Emails from Marketing Cloud Connect AB Test

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, content-builder

I'd love to be able to select Content Builder emails within Marketing Cloud Connect AB testing, but it looks like I'm restricted to Classic Content only. Is this something that can be changed by support or is this really locked in to Classic only?

Comment: This is definitely an available option. If you do not see it in your account I would contact your rep and/or support to get this activated.

Comment: @Gortonington I'm afraid I heard back from Support and they said that it is NOT possible to send Content Builder emails from the Marketing Cloud Connect app when sending an AB test. They acknowledged that it sucks that they're sunsetting Classic Content in January and they're frantically working on a workaround.

Comment: Apologies, I didnt see the connector app part of it.

Answer (score 1):

As of October 25, 2018, Salesforce Support has responded and said there is no way to send an AB Test using Content Builder Content within the Marketing Cloud Connect app within Sales Cloud. They apologized since they are very well aware that Classic Content will be sunset in January and are currently working on a workaround to this problem.